# vuetify v1.1 can I set some transparency to the v-card color?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

currently I display a v-card as following :

```
                      <v-parallax :src="require('../../assets/images/member.jpeg')" height="100%">
                        <v-container grid-list-xl pt-5 style="max-height: 10em;">
                        <v-layout row justify-center align-center>
                          <v-flex xs6 sm6 md3>
                            <v-card class="member__account flexcard">
                              <v-card-title class="section__title justify-center">
                                <div class="headline mt-1 mb-1 display-1 text-xs-center">MY ACCOUNT</div>
                              </v-card-title>
                            </v-card>
                          </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                      </v-container>
```

...

The tritle "MY ACCOUNT" is displayed balc on white v-card background

However I have a v-parallax image below, and I would like to give some transparency to the v-card white background to let the parallax image appears a little bit inside it ....

Is it possible ? if yes, how ...  thanks for feedback

Comment: `color="transparent"` on v-card?

Comment: thanks for feedback, yes it gives a transparent v-card ... but I cannot play on the opacity...

Answer (score 9):

You can use **rgb** in color property. it's seem look like this

```
<v-card color="rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.2)"> </v-card>
```

you can set transparency in last value of rgb.
**rgb(color, color, color, setTransparency)**

you can set value of transparency from 0 to 1.

1 = no transparency
0 = 100% transparent

Comment: Thanks - really needed this!

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED :  just changing the default .transparent class :

from

```
.transparent {
  background-color: transparent!important;
  border-color: transparent!important;
 }
```

to

```
.transparent {
   background-color: white!important;
   opacity: 0.65;
   border-color: transparent!important;
 }
```